# Selectbox unselectable in lower part in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

For some reason the selectbox is unselectable at the lower part in Safari.
It's really hard to explain in code. Here is the website it's the country selectbox that's not working.

http://mirror.thnk.org/login/signup/

```
<span>
    <span class="select" id="selectland">--- Select ---</span><select class="styled" name="land">
            <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

I tried all combinations in Css but nothing worked.
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari don't understand the height in select box so use line height with height like below.

```
.profileBox select{
  margin-left: 2px;
  width: 296px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  top: 15px;
}
```